# How to fit normal coordinate system with image coordinate system?

Tags: c#, image, coordinates

Quick question:

I have these coordinates:

[image]

And I draw them on a Bitmap Image:

```
    foreach (var point in MyCoords)
    {
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(null, new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua), 1), new Point(point.X+100, point.Y+100) , 1, 1); 
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Why shapes do not match? Because the bitmap pixel y-axis is flipped(0 top and max is bottom).

**Fix:**

```
    foreach (var point in MyCoords)
    {
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(null, new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua), 1), new Point(point.X+100, (Bitmap.Height - point.Y)-100), 1, 1);
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Is there a better way to work on my coordinate system in the back code and then to display it "right"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System.Graphics routines that are based on GDI+ Calls "inherit" the coordinate system that is baked into Windows. It is a pure matter of definition. There is no way to configure an own system. Another way of thinking would be to define a set of drawing operations and apply a transformation of this whole set (this approach is more common in vector based graphic libraries). So at least you could put the code for coordinate transformation in one single place (it would be horrible, if `new Point(point.X+100, (Bitmap.Height - point.Y)-100)` is repeated through the whole code base). What's about an extension method:

```
public static class PointExtensions
{
    public static Point ToSystem(this Point point, Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        return new Point(point.X + 100, bitmap.Height - point.Y - 100);
    }
}
```

That will lead to more readable code:

```
   foreach (var point in MyCoords)
    {
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(
              null, 
              new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua), 1),                
              point.ToSystem(bitmap),  /// <- better to read
              1, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to apply a `Transform` to the `Graphics` instance that will modify points as they are drawn.

Something like this should work, as it flips the Y axis:

```
drawingContext.ScaleTransform( 1.0f, -1.0f, MatrixOrder.Prepend );
```

---

From comments, it seems you are actually using a `DrawingContext` instance instead of `Graphics`.  Try this:

```
drawingContext.PushTransform(new ScaleTransform(0.0f, -1.0f));
```

Unlike the method on the `Graphics` class, the `DrawingContext` uses a stack of `Transforms`, so you will need to make sure you are only applying this **once** per `DrawingContext`.  You may also need to use one of the other overloads for the `ScaleTransform` constructor to take the size of the image in to account (`CenterX` and `CenterY`).

Comment: Hi it says that `drawingContext` does not contain a definition for `ScaleTransform` and my Resharper says no library suggested do you have any idea why?

Comment: What class is `drawingContext`?  I assumed it was a `Graphics` instance, which has `ScaleTransform`, from the signature of `DrawEllipse`, but if it is some other class you will need a different solution.

Comment: Hi it comes from System.Windows.Media and not Graphics. Would you recommend using one over another? But `PushTransform` did not show it "right", still flipped..